# Getting UnreadmessagesCount

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question I have here is for some reason when the getInboxUnreadMessagesCount js function is ran then it comes up with a different number then what is there to begin with and keep in mind there is no new message being sent. When I run the php dashboard functions they both are returning the correct numbers but I think the issue lies with the last line of code with the messageTimer

Anybody even have any thoughts onto what it might be? I'm hoping someone can figure it out.

```
var $messageCountJSON;
var messageTimer = '';
var messageInterval = 5;

//assumed JSON response is {"count":"20"} for example sake.

function getInboxUnreadMessagesCount(displayElementID) {
    $.get('dashboard/getInboxUnreadMessagesCount', function (data) {
        $messageCountJSON = data;
    }, 'json');
    if (displayElementID != null && displayElementID != undefined && displayElementID != '') {
        //$('#'+displayElementID).html($messageCountJSON);
        if (parseInt($('#' + displayElementID).text()) < parseInt($messageCountJSON)) {
            $.jGrowl("You have received a new private message!", { theme: 'information' });
            $('#' + displayElementID).html($messageCountJSON).css({ "display": "block" });
        }
        if (parseInt($messageCountJSON) == 0) {
            $('#' + displayElementID).html($messageCountJSON).css({ "display": "none" });
        }
    }
}

function getInboxMessagesCount(displayElementID) {
    $.get('dashboard/getInboxMessagesCount', function (data) {
        $messageCountJSON = data;
    }, 'json');
    if (displayElementID != null && displayElementID != undefined && displayElementID != '') {
        //$('#'+displayElementID).html($messageCountJSON);
        if (parseInt($('#' + displayElementID).text()) < parseInt($messageCountJSON)) {
            $('#' + displayElementID).html($messageCountJSON);
        }
        if (parseInt($messageCountJSON) == 0) {
            $('#' + displayElementID).html($messageCountJSON);
        }
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    messageTimer = setInterval(function () { getInboxUnreadMessagesCount('notifications'); getInboxMessagesCount('inboxCount'); }, messageInterval * 1000);
});

//you can optionally kill the timed interval with something like
//$('#pmMessagesIcon').click(function(){clearInterval(messageTimer);})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the message count before it's received:

```
// Here you create an asynchronous request to the server.
 $.get('dashboard/getInboxUnreadMessagesCount', function (data) {
     // This section of your code will only run after you get the JSON response
    $messageCountJSON = data;
}, 'json');
// Code here will run immediately after the request is fired,
// and probably  before the JSON response arrives
```

You have to move your big `if` statements to inside each `$.get()` callback function.